# how to center modal window with body hidden after scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have model dialog, while model dialog open setting up body `overflow:hidden` this makes model window display half only. onclose resetting the body overflow.

body height is more than window size and scrolled some where than open modal dialog.

How to get center display modal dialog?

[image]

Comment: What library are you using for the modal?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can create function to position your modal depending on window size, like this:

Something like this:

```
    function repositionModal(modal){
    var windowW = $(window).width(),
        windowH = $(window).height(),
        modalW = modal.width(),
        modalH = modal.height();

    if (modalW>windowW) modal.width(windowW);
    if (modalH>windowH) modal.height(windowH);
    modal.css({
        "top": (windowH-modalH)/2)+"px",
        "left": (windowW-modalW)/2)+"px"
    });
    }
```

Then call this function when modal is invoked, and, probably also on window resize

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     if($(".my-modal").is(:visible)){
         repositionModal($(".my-modal"))
     }
})
```

Comment: I want to prevent body scrolling but modal window should scroll

Comment: I thought you already had solution for this - set body to overflow:hidden, and the problem was to make modal dialog centered

Comment: yah I want to make model dialog centerd